# Filechooser doesn't do anything

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

So for a project I'm making I need to import pictures. But the only problem is that my filter, filters everything and I never recieve A file back

```
public class FileChooser extends JPanel{

    public FileChooser(){

        JFileChooser fileopen=new JFileChooser();
        FileFilter filter=new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpg files","jpg");
        fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
        int ret =fileopen.showDialog(null,"Open file");

        if (ret==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File[] picture=fileopen.getSelectedFiles();
            System.out.println(picture[0].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying it doesn't print anything after you've selected some files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the javadoc for [`JFileChooser#getSelectedFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFiles%28%29)

> Returns a list of selected files **if the file chooser is set to allow multiple selection**

Therefore enable the [multi select option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled%28boolean%29) for the `JFileChooser` `fileopen` so that the dialog can return a selected `File` array list....otherwise the resultant array will always be empty and an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will result when attempting to access the first element

```
fileopen.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
```